# Countvectorize to count the number of words in a huge file

Tags: python, scikit-learn, count, word-count

Hi dear I have a problem. I want to count and sum all words in my large dataset, about 2 GB for 3400000 rows. The code I wrote is:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
df1 = pd.read_pickle("tweet_post_stop.pkl")
```

Then

```
cv = CountVectorizer()
cv_fit = cv.fit_transform(df1.Testo_token)
```

All suits well, but I have a problem with segment part:

```
word_list = cv.get_feature_names_out()
```

```
count_list = cv_fit.toarray().sum(axis= 0)
```

With the last command the kernel dieds and I can't do what I want, that is to say to count all the occurrence of the words inside the dataset and sum them, to see the first 20 words most used by the people. How can I improve my code let it doing what I want? I think it is a problem for the RAM, but I have 24 GB of RAM. I tried this code on a part of my Dataframe. I saved the first 100 rows on another Dataframe, imported it and tried on 100 rows my code and it works. What I can do in order to perform what I want on all dataset?
Thank you for the time spent for me and for the patience

Answer (score 0):

`CountVectorizer` will produce a matrix that is really sparse (This matrix will have a lot of `0` and few `1` per row).

For example if you have a vocabulary of 10000 words, the encoded sentence `I love Stackoverflow` will result in an array of size `(10000,)` containing 3 times 1 and otherwise 0.

As you can imagine, this would take a lot of space in the memory for nothing. To tackle this issue, `CountVectorizer` produce a sparse matrix and the previous sentence will only be represented by 3 values the index position of the words and its count.

When you are performing `cv_fit.toarray()` you are basically transforming each sentences into a numpy array of size `(10000,)`.

Therefore you should perform this operation directly on the sparse matrix like in the example below:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
features = vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
freqs = zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names_out(), np.asarray(X.sum(axis=0)).ravel())
print(sorted(freqs, key=lambda x: -x[1]))
```

Comment: I tried to do in this way. Also if I don't understand what you're doing, I tried to know if it works, but I have this waning:
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit.

What I can do? Than you @Antoine Dubuis for your time

Comment: On which rows does this warning happens?

Comment: on all dataset I received this problem @Antoine Dubuis

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I found, was to decrease the number of features as a parameter of CountVectorizer, in this way:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features = n)
```

where "n" is a number that could be representative of the our principal featres.